# Regex to find all UUIDs in which the letters in every group are sorted alphabetically

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

A UUID is made up of 5 groups, separated by '-', consisting out of hexadecimal characters. I am trying to make a regex expression to find all UUIDs in which the letters in every group are sorted in alphabetical order.

Input:

```
9a578cf1-bc9f-49ad-8294-a61b736088c5
64efc3d9-448a-4902-a6c6-61849ac6c7ef
75b39f65-b614-427a-af62-922534bee490
```

Output:

```
9a578cf1-bc9f-49ad-8294-a61b736088c5
```

The letters in every group are: acf bcf ad abc, which are ordered in alphabetical order.

The letters in every group in the second UUID aren't sorted alphabetically: efc and accef

A group can also only have the same letter once, so 'bee' like in the third UUID would also not be considered alphabetically ordered.

I tried using the following grep command:

```
grep -P "^[0-9]*a?[0-9]*b?[0-9]*c?[0-9]*d?[0-9]*e?[0-9]*f?[0-9]*(-[0-9]*a?[0-9]*b?[0-9]*c?[0-9]*d?[0-9]*e?[0-9]*f?[0-9]*){4}$" file.txt
```

But this gives me a backtracking error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me with GNU `grep` both with version 3.7 and 3.8 albeit very slowly.

Switching to a different `grep` implementation and/or version, or a different regexp engine might help. There's nothing perl specific in your code, you could use `-E` in place of `-P` there for instance (the [`egrep` algorithm avoiding the need to backtrack](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html) here).

In  any case backtracking is not necessary and would be counterproductive here, so you might as well disable it altogether with `(?>...)` (a perl extension).

```
grep -Px '(?>(\d*a?\d*b?\d*c?\d*d?\d*e?\d*f?\d*)(?:-(?1)){4})'
```

With a few extra shortcuts:

- `-x`  in place of using `^` and `$` anchors
- `\d` in place of `[0-9]` (perl extension)
- `(?1)` to recall the same  regex as used for the first group to avoid repetition (perl extension).

Comment: Seems to work instantly for me with GNU grep 3.6, though. I just wonder why there'd be a significant change for the worse there.